# How to Proxy A Request at Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, proxy

I want to proxy requests between a client and server to maintain security. Client will not send its data to server. They will send it to my proxy application and I will remove some parameters and will send it to server. Then I will send the response directly to the client.

I use Spring and resttemplate but I get some weird errors. I try that:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/emo -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id"        : "id1",
  "domain" : "domain"   
 }
]'
```

and that:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/emo?passo=true' --data-binary @web.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

How can I copy all the parameters and headers from request and send it to server? When doing a proxy at Post request I tried to get data and realized that sometimes this works:

```
Object data = ((WebApplicationContext) uriInfo).getContainerRequest().getHeaderValue("-d");
```

and sometimes that:

```
Object data  = ((Form) ((WebApplicationContext) uriInfo).getProperties().get("com.sun.jersey.api.representation.form")).keySet().toString();
```

I need a generic solution. I think that instead of copying data and some other parameters I can copy UriInfo, change something on it and then send it to server.

Comment: Why don't you write a Spring Interceptor or a Servlet Filter for the task, why it needs to be a proxy?

Comment: I used `proxy` just as a term. Can I drop some parameters with interceptor or servlet filter?

Comment: In servlet filter, you have access to the current `ServletRequest` which is the `HttpServletRequest` so you can retrieve the URL and the parameters before processing the request by your Servlet/Controller.

Comment: I can still access that with: @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest Main problem is how can I construct a new request copy of the incoming one (not exactly copy of it, some parameters will be dropped by me)

Comment: Have you tried dropping the parameters in the Interceptor/Filter and then let it continue the processing?

Comment: Client and server are remote machines. Do you think that interceptor works for me? Can I redirect to a remote URL with its all header and data information?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it. And in a decent real world application, client and server are remote machines...

Comment: I wrote that because I will not intercept my own Controllers. Could you give me example for it?